# Getting IllegalStateException for line-awesome.min.css with a Vaadin upgrade

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I've tried all the additional steps such as running `mvn clean install`, `npm install`, and so on, as well we deleting the `node_modules` folder. Even invalidating Intellij's cache. Nothing seems to help.

That being said I did notice when downloading the sample project that there is the new dependency below. Not sure why it's not automatically included as a dependency of Vaadin but nonetheless I've added it and the line-awesome.min.css file is in the included jar when inspecting the jar in Intellij.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.parttio</groupId>
    <artifactId>line-awesome</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

However when I try to run the server on every page load I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Asset '/line-awesome/dist/line-awesome/css/line-awesome.min.css' is not found in project frontend directory, default development bundle or in the application bundle 'src/main/dev-bundle/assets/'. 
Verify that the asset is available in 'frontend/themes/myApplicationName/' directory and is added into the 'assets' block of the 'theme.json' file.
```

I looked in the sample todo project by Vaadin and I can't find any differences in my project. The `theme.json`, etc. are all the same. My project does have a `dev-bundle` folder that's generated but otherwise everything looks identical.

I'm using Vaadin 24.0.4 and it started to happen during an upgrade of Vaadin. I'm using Java 20 but compiling to 17 because the todo project also uses 17 (because it's an LTS release I assume).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try removing the line-awesome import in theme/styles.css - that should resolve it.

Comment: Interesting. Looking at my git history it looks like it was generated by Vaadin at some point. I assume then that it's no longer needed. In any case thank you, that did the trick.

Comment: It was included in projects generated from start.vaadin.com. Because it wasn't a framework feature, it didn't get mentioned in release/upgrade notes. This is of course not an ideal situation because it leads to people's projects breaking without clear instructions on how to fix them. Something we need to improve going forward.

Comment: Ah. That makes a lot of sense. Thank you again for the help, it's much appreciated.